# How to enable code completion on Coderunner tool for swift language

Tags: swift, coderunner

Any help with swift language code completion on coderunner, would be much appreciated.
On the website https://coderunnerapp.com/ its claimed that it does support it, but not sure if I need to enable it explicitly or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup Active Directory

In Terminal run

```
xcrun swift --version
```

If you see the version information, you’re all set. If the command fails with xcrun: error: unable to find utility **"swift"**, not a developer tool or in PATH, you need to set the active developer directory:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

#### Create a Swift Template in CodeRunner

Open Preferences and switch to the Languages tab. Create a new entry in the list and name it **“Swift”**.

In the **“Run Command:”** text field, enter this command:

```
xcrun swift -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) -i $filename
```

The **“Code Template:”** field should contain the code you want to start with when you create a blank Swift file in CodeRunner.

In the **“File Extension”** field, enter swift.

Comment: Thanks for respoding, added but getting error
`xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox.`

Comment: Did you try to run it in terminal?

Comment: Also make sure to specify the preferred version of Xcode when running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode(Version Number).app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Yes I did run it on terminal first and it suggested me to remove -i as part of filename
and I do get the version number when I run
`xcrun swift --version
Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0`

Comment: Since you're in sandbox add a temp exception, check [this out] (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html)

Comment: Thank you but, not sure where to add the entitlements changes, I'm just trying to do a print("Hello") in the editor